# Output XMLHttp response line by line

Tags: vbscript, stream, xmlhttprequest

I need to grab a log file from a URL and then print the log file line by line. I can successfully get the file this way:

```
Dim filePath,fileName

filePath = "http://localhost/osat/spawn_pi_logs"
fileName = "/Spawn.log"
FilePath = filePath & fileName
Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
req.open "GET", FilePath, False
req.send

If req.Status = 200 Then
    Response.Write "Found the file<br>"
    Response.Write req.responsetext
End If
```

That code writes the text of my log file to the screen in one huge ugly blob.  I want to walk through it, format it, search it, etc and write it out with code similar to this:

```
Do While Not TextStream.AtEndOfStream
    Dim sLine
    sLine = TextStream.readLine
    sLine = sLine & "<br>"
    Response.Write sLine
Loop
```

However, how do I convert my req object (which has a generic stream at req.ResponseStream) and convert it to a Text Stream?

Comment: Returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array containing a specified number of substrings.

 

`Split(expression[, delimiter[, count[, compare]]])`

Answer (score 2):

You can save the response to a text file by incorporating an ADO Stream and writing the `responseBody`:

```
If req.Status = 200 Then

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write req.responseBody
        .SaveToFile "c:\myfile.txt"
        .Close
    End With

End If
```

Then you can open your text file using `OpenTextFile()` and read it as a `TextStream`.

But, you could just split your `responseText` into an array with the `Split()` function and not worry about saving and reading a text file:

```
If req.Status = 200 Then

    ' Create a line array...
    a = Split(req.responseText, vbCrLf)

    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        ' Process each line
    Next

End If
```

Comment: Thank you Bond.  I did want to avoid creating another text file.  The Split solution worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you PHD443322.  This code works great:

```
a = Split(req.responsetext, vbCrLf)
for each x in a
    response.write(x & "<br />")
next
```

The key was not only the Split command, but also using the VBScript vbCrLf constant to set the delimiter.